# Многомерный массив JSON в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Добрый день! Имеется следующий массив JSON:

```
{
"boxes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Шляпная коробочка",
        "flowers" : "Розы",
        "types" : {
            "MINI" : {
                "size" : "15x15x15см",
                "price" : "1000"
            },
            "M" : {
                "size" : "20х20х21см",
                "price" : "1300"
            },
            "L" : {
                "size" : "22х22х23см",
                "price" : "1700"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name" : "Коробочка в форме сердца",
        "flowers" : "Кустовые розы",
        "types" : {
            "MINI" : {
                "size" : "16x13см",
                "price" : "1200"
            },
            "M" : {
                "size" : "19х15см",
                "price" : "1500"
            },
            "L" : {
                "size" : "22х17см",
                "price" : "1700"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Как получить, к примеру, все данные из элемента "types"?
Т.е. я получил все из boxes:

```
$.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.boxes.length;i++){               
            console.log('Название: ' + data.boxes[i].name + '\n'); 
        }
});
```

Но при попытках встроить еще один цикл for, все накрывается медным тазом.

UPD:

```
 for (var key in data.boxes[i].types) {
                console.log ('Доступные типы:' + key);                  
            }
```

После этого кода появились доступные типы, т.е. "MINI", "M" и "L"...но неужели так нужно идти по всему многомерному объекту?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых этот JSON синтексически неверен (перепутаны закрывающие скобки в последней строке), во вторых логически (подчиненные объекты types это объекты со свойствами "MINI", "M" и "L", а не массивы с автоиндексацией). Впрочем массивы в json это тоже объекты, свойства в которых задаются автоматически ("0","1","2", ...). 
Исходя из вашей логики json должен иметь вид:

```
{
"boxes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Шляпная коробочка",
        "flowers" : "Розы",
        "types" : [
            "MINI" : {
                "size" : "15x15x15см",
                "price" : "1000"
            },
            "M" : {
                "size" : "20х20х21см",
                "price" : "1300"
            },
            "L" : {
                "size" : "22х22х23см",
                "price" : "1700"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Коробочка в форме сердца",
        "flowers" : "Кустовые розы",
        "types" : [
            "MINI" : {
                "size" : "16x13см",
                "price" : "1200"
            },
            "M" : {
                "size" : "19х15см",
                "price" : "1500"
            },
            "L" : {
                "size" : "22х17см",
                "price" : "1700"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Тогда будет работать и первый способ организации цикла

```
for(var key1=0;i<data.boxes.length;key1++){  
  for(var key2=0;i<data.boxes[key1].types.length;key2++){ 
    var something = data.boxes[key1].types[key2];
    ...
```

Но второй способ более универсален и более правильный для json:

```
for (var key1 in data.boxes) {
  for (var key2 in data.boxes[key1].types) {
     var something = data.boxes[key1].types[key2]; 
     ...
```

Он будет работать и с вашим и с моим вариантами json (при условии правильно расставленных закрывающих скобок).

Comment: Спасибо огромное :)

Comment: UPD. что-то не так...
мне sublime text пишет, что JSON неправильно построен, а $.getJSON не дает ничего...

Ошибки:
https://pp.vk.me/c637326/v637326475/316a9/AT6Dh1elflM.jpg

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: скобки проверьте все